# Jcommander not supporting backslash

Tags: java, console-application

Jcommander parameter not supporting backslash.
is there any way which supports jcommander parameter to provide the value as user entered with backslashes

Comment: backslash has a different meaning in the command line. It is used as escape char.

Answer (score 0):

Backslash has a different meaning in the command line. It is used as escape char.  Users will have to enclose their parameter in double quotes to work around this.

Comment: i have tried with doule quotes its not working .@Parameter(names = { "-name" }, required = true, description = "")
 public String name; then when i going to get the value with description.getparameter its not taking backslash

Comment: The double quotes will have to supplied from command line, when user is running your program. Eg: `YourProgram -name "Some\Name"`

Comment: i have provide with double quotes but its not taking. i am using Jcommander 1.17